# request in getInitialProps fails when using a request wrapper class but works with axios

Tags: node.js, laravel, express, axios, next.js

In my NextJS application in getInitialProps I am using this wrapper class for Axios: https://gist.github.com/sheharyarn/7f43ef98c5363a34652e60259370d2cb

When I do a request to my api (laravel) like this it fails with the error message in the wrapper class (line 34 of the wrapper class above):

> Request Failed: undefined
>
> Error Message: console.debug is not a function

```
const response = await request({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'api/profile',
            data: {
                username: req.params.username,
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            return {
                initialProps: res.data,
            };
        }).catch(() => {
            return {};
        });
```

However when I use axios out of the box it works fine (i get back initialProps):

```
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/profile', {
            params: {
                username: req.params.username,
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            return {
                initialProps: res.data,
            };
        }).catch((error) => {
            return {};
        });
```

**Can someone see whats causing this issue?**

**Also when I do that exact same request() call in componentDidMount it works fine.**

In that request.js wrapper class, I have it configured as follows:

```
const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
});
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but the transpiler broke it perhaps? Also, _Note: Starting with Chromium 58 this method only appears in Chromium browser consoles when level "Verbose" is selected._ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

Comment: but only breaks in getInitialProps

Comment: ahhh thanks! Works when i change to console.log. Did not think that could cause the issue, works now!